# How to simultaneously apply augmentation to X_train and y_train

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am facing this problem of creating a dataset from a very few images.

Both input (`X_train`) and output (`y_train`) contains (28x28) size images such as MNIST. For example in my code:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
y_train=X_train

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(zca_whitening=True)
```

How can I fit this `datagen` to both `X_train`  and `y_train` simultaneously and save them in a dataset array. Don't want to pass it to training.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Why would you need to augment your y_train? Assuming that you are doing some kind of binary/multi-class classification ,what is the purpose of augmenting your ground truth labels?

Comment: I have as input x_train defocused images (Acquired from experiment) and at output y_train (focused images). 
Since my data is limited i want to increase my dataset. Therefore, when i apply effects on input i have to do so to the output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that augmentation per se is not applied on the target variable `y_train` but only on the input variables `X_train`. The generator is only going to reproduce the same ground truth labels `y` for the newly generated `X`.

Hence fitting the generator is only using `X_train`:

```
datagen.fit(X_train)
```

If you do not want to pass the augmented data to training, you can loop over the generator **after fitting** to get the generated samples:

```
for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32):
# Do whatever you want with the generated X_batch and y_batch.
```

I understand that is what you are willing to do.
See examples on [keras doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator).

Comment: Like i mentioned I want to apply augmentation to both X_train and y_train.
How can i achieve this. My input x_train is a set of defocused images(acquired from experiemnt) and output y_train= focused images. I want to multiply my dataset and for that when i augment, the effect i apply on x_train needs to be applied to y_train

Comment: I would say that keras is not able to do it. Another option will be to use [scikit-image.transform](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html) to generate the new images using the same transformations for both `X_train` and `y_train`.